# how to get USB HID ID of pressed keyboard keys

Tags: usb, keyboard, input-device, hid

What I want to do: Get the **USB HID IDs** when I press the **keys** of my [truly ergonomic](http://www.trulyergonomic.com/) **keyboard** to be able to [reprogram the firmware](http://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=38943.0) of the keyboard.

I know there is this [list from microsoft](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/translate.pdf) with a lot of USB HID IDs.

But it would be easier to find the ID of a key by just typing it and seeing it displayed in a program. Especially for some media keys, which I don’t find in that list from microsoft.

Does such a program exist? Could be a command line program. Linux preferred, but Windows would be an option.

PS: I have seen, that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873975/how-to-capture-raw-hid-input-on-linux) on stackoverflow has an interesting answer. But I can’t find `/dev/usb/hiddev0` on my system (Fedora 17).

### Update

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072035/hid-callback-function-linux-equivalent/13072119#13072119) the answer from @Andy Ross helped me to at least get some output, when pressing a key. I did

```
xxd -c 144 /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.1:1.0-event-kbd
```

But it is still not really readable. And not always the same, when I press the same key.

### Update2

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834220/how-to-read-out-an-usb-rfid-reader-imitating-an-hid-keyboard-using-linux-and-pyt) a [python script](http://bit.ly/kZkO2b) is linked, that reads the input device and should print it. But on this computer at work I have no rights to access the device with this python script.

Comment: Describe your specific application which will allow users to provide better solutions that specifically meets your needs.

Comment: @mdpc There is nothing more to say. I want to easily get the USB HID ID numbers of my keyboard without having to search in the linked list from microsoft. Maybe this question is better on stackoverflow? superuser seems more for users, not for hackers. can someone move this question?

Comment: Hi erik. I don't think it's absolutely necessary to move your question to Stack Overflow, as we Super Users surely also do some hacking here and there :) If you'd *really* like to have it moved, leave me a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The answer is**:

```
su -c "while true; do od --read-bytes=144 --width=144 -x /dev/input/event3 | awk 'NF > 1 { print \$12 }'; done"
```

### Explanition

With the tree command I have found this

```
$ tree /dev/input/by-path
/dev/input/by-path/
├── pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.1:1.0-event-kbd -> ../event3
├── pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.1:1.1-event -> ../event4
├── pci-0000:00:1d.2-usb-0:1:1.0-event-mouse -> ../event2
└── pci-0000:00:1d.2-usb-0:1:1.0-mouse -> ../mouse0
```

Ok, so `/dev/input/event3` is **my keyboard**.

The `od` command dumps files in octal and other formats.

- With the `-x` option it dumps hexadecimal.
- And with the `--width=144` option it dumps only one line per keypress (one line is 144 Bytes long).
- Option `--read-bytes=144` quits `od` after 144 Bytes.

The `awk` command prints the 12th field out of the whole line. That only, if the number of fields `NF` is greater then 1, because every second line is just a line break.

The `while true` loop around the whole thing is because if I type some letter keys it breaks. I get no more results, only `0000`. But the `od` command quits reading after 144 Bytes (one key press). After that it is restarted. There is surely a better fix for that, but this is a good workaround.

**Example output** (I pressed a few times <kbd>Return</kbd>, <kbd>RightCtrl</kbd> and <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, which gives me the correct numbers when comparing to this [document from microsoft (PDF)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/translate.pdf) or [this text file document](http://www.freebsddiary.org/APC/usb_hid_usages.php))

```
0028
0028
0028
00e4
00e4
00e4
002a
002a
002a
```

Answer (score -1):

`xev` in Linux will help you.

Good Luck.

Comment: No, I want the USB HID ID numbers. Not the X keycodes. `xev` only prints X keycodes.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Maybe use dmesg|grep hid?

Comment: No, sorry. `dmesg` does not give you an event for every key press. But that is what I want to have.